# Why F# library not having dll version?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#, functional-programming

I have created f# library, Now I want to set some version number to the same. But it has no option to set the version number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio, the project template should have added an `AssemblyInfo.fs` file to your project. If it hasn't, you should probably check your Visual Studio installation, but you can add that file yourself.

If the file is already there, you can edit these attributues:

```
[<assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>]
```

If the file wasn't there, you can add these yourself, but you'll need to end the file with an expression:

```
do
    ()
```

Again, the template should already have added that.

Comment: This is really good to add version for F# dll. But still I can not able to set the version in F# project properties like c# project properties. 
Also both are the different things(C# dll version and F# dll version). We are assign explicitly version to the F# project.